# match multiple items with attribute within a loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops

```
<div class="item" rel="a">1</div>
<div class="item" rel="b">2</div>

<div class="receive" rel="a">1</div>
<div class="receive" rel="b">2</div>

.item[rel='a'] {
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    background: pink;
}
.item[rel='b'] {
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    background: orange;
    margin-left:20px;
}
.receive {
    margin-top:20px;
    border:1px solid;
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
}
```

How can I make the receiver to receive the color of the items? I can do

```
bg = $('.item').css('background');
$('.receive').css('background',bg);
```

but I want it to be able to match using the 'rel' attribute, I have multiple receiver. Should I loop?

Comment: how many records do you have ..?

Comment: Why not use simple CSS for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do it in each loop.

```
$('.item').each(function(idx) {
    var rel = $(this).attr('rel');
    var bg = $(this).css('background');
    $('.recieve[rel="' + rel + '"]').css('background', bg);
});
```

I suppose that's what you want.

You can loop over `.item` or `.recieve`, it doesn't matter at the end of the day.
Here is a fiddle to show that it works: http://jsfiddle.net/Lg6yw7bj/1/

Answer (score 0):

`.css()` method in jquery accepts a callback function so you can make use of it.

You can try this:

```js
$('.recieve').addClass('item'); // just add the class to make it work.

/*$('.recieve').css('background', function(i){
    return $('.item').eq(i).css('background');
});*/
```

```css
.item[rel='a'] {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: pink;
}
.item[rel='b'] {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: orange;
  margin-left: 20px;
}
.recieve {
  margin-top: 20px;
  border: 1px solid;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="item" rel="a">1</div>
<div class="item" rel="b">2</div>

<div class="recieve" rel="a">1</div>
<div class="recieve" rel="b">2</div>
```

Comment: `i` denotes the index of the element in the loop. @JamesLemon

Comment: `.eq()` is a special selector to filter the collection.

Comment: This solution relies on the unspoken condition that the `.item` and `.receive` elements appear in the same order and number.

Comment: even this can work `$('.recieve').addClass('item');` see the updates.